# Acronym input text and reverse it

Tags: python, python-3.x

My task is to turn the input text to acronym and reverse it. The word should be more than 3 characters long and do not contain symbols such as `,!'?.` For example if I have this sentence `"That was quite easy?"` the function should return `EQT`

I have done so far:

```
def acr(message):

    words = message.split()
    if check_length(words) is False:
        return "the input long!"
    else:
        first_letters = []
        for word in words:
            first_letters.append(word[0])
        result = "".join(first_letters)
        return reverse(result.upper())


def check(word):
    if len(word) > 3:
        return False


def check_length(words):
    if len(words) > 50:
        return False


def rev(message):
    reversed_message = message[::-1]
    return reversed_message
```

I have problems with `check` function. How to correctly control the length of words and symbols?

Comment: [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) sounds like what you 're looking for

Comment: where do you use the checkword function?

Comment: None of your `check` functions ever returns a truthy value (but just either `False` or `None`), also they do not do what the docstring says.

Comment: Also, do you want to "reverse" the acronym as in "reverse the order of characters in the string", or "reverse it to the original sentence it is an acronym of"?

Comment: @tobias_k The firs one. At the moment function returns reversed acronym using all words. "That was quite easy, huh?" --> "HEQWT" But the result should be "EQT" cuz the length of some words is less than 3.
What about "False" and "None". It is one of the task conditions. "check_word" and "check_length_message" should return bol values

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 At the moment nowhere cuz the function is not ready. But planning to use it in "acronymize" function after "for word in words:"

Comment: Try this: `print(''.join(list(reversed(''.join([t[0] for t in [''.join([r for r in e if r not in ",!'?."]) for e in string.split(' ')] if len(t)>3]).upper()))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hacky in the sense that a comma is technically a special character (but you want the 'e' from easy), but this works perfectly for your example. Set up the "if" statement in the "for word in words" section.

```
def acronymize(message):
"""Turn the input text into the acronym and reverse it, if the text is not too long."""
words = message.split()
if check_message_length(words) is False:
    return "Sorry, the input's just too long!"
else:
    first_letters = []
    for word in words:
        if len(word) > 3 and word.isalnum()== True or (len(word) > 4 and ',' in word): #satisfies all conditions. Allows commas, but no other special characters.
            first_letters.append(word[0])
            result = "".join(first_letters)
    return reverse(result.upper())
```

Basically the 'if' condition became if you have word of length > 3 characters AND the word is alphanumeric (then that satisfies all conditions) OTHERWISE (OR) if there is a comma next to the word (there will be len(word)+1 characters) and it will have a comma (,), that still satisfies the previous conditions, then populate the first_letters list.

Otherwise, ignore the word.

This way you don't even have to set up a check_word function.

This spits out the answer

> 'EQT'

A couple more examples from my code:

```
Input: Holy cow, does this really work??
Output: 'RTDH'
```

** Note that it did NOT include the word 'cow' because it did not have more than 3 letters.

```
Input: Holy cows, this DOES work!!
Output: 'DTCH'
```

** Note, now the term 'cows' gets counted because it has more than 3 letters.

You can similarly add any exceptions that you want (!, ? and .) using the 'or' format:

Ex: or (len(word) > 4 and '!' in word) or (len(word) > 4 and '?' in word)

The only assumption made for this is that the sentence is grammatically correct (as in, it won't have exclamation marks followed by commas).

It can be further cleaned up by making a list of the special characters that you would allow and passing that list into the or clause.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

`re.findall(r'(\w)\w{3,}', sentence)` finds first letter of every at least four letter word

```
''.join(reversed(re.findall(r'(\w)\w{3,}', sentence))).upper()
```

[re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

---

If you want to ignore words preceding non-word characters, use `(\w)\w{3,},?(?:$|\s)` – this also allows a comma explicitly.

```
''.join(reversed(re.findall(r'(\w)\w{3,},?(?:$|\s)', sentence))).upper()
```

Comment: That doesn't handle non-word characters. E.g., it would match "hello!".

Comment: @Wyatt It would match `hello` in `hello!`.

Comment: Right, but it should ignore "hello!" altogether.